# eBay like database structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I'm trying to get my head around eBay like structural database.

Given that each type of products has different columns I had to get products table then products descriptions table which is a meta table with key and value columns with product_id as foreign key for Products table

I've also got Specifications table which is hasAndBelongsToMany relationship with Subsubcategory table (which has belongsTo with Subcategory and then belongsTo Category relations)
So I've got joining table for Specifications Subsubcategory then also got Specification_Category which Specifications table belongsTo.

Now. I want my users to select a product with all those specifications of the product when they want to create a product selling page or have an option to create their custom product then enter those specific details into the Product Detail Meta Table based on pre-defined columns that are read from Specifications of that Subsubcategory.

To give you an example:

I'm now adding Specification using Scaffolding feature of Cakephp and I have a form with Name ie - 1TB, Specification Category - Hard Drive Capacity (belongsTo) and Subsubcategory - ie. Laptops, Desktops (hasAndBelongsTo)

Is this the correct way to structure something like this?

Comment: i would suggest you to create tables for products,categories,manufactures then add a products_details table, in which you set the product's related manufacture_id and category_id for example, i think this is a standard approach, so anytime you need products details like category or manufacture you use the SELECT JOIN by id

Comment: i mean if you don't have strong basics on db structuring, go with standard schemas, use separated tables i mean :P

Comment: I think you have confused what I'm trying to say. The columns must be variable so it caters for different types of key names for specifications of each product type (aka Subsubcategory). This is why I've created a meta table with key and value columns otherwise I would have a table for each Subsubcategory and there are more than 500 of those so it means 500+ tables which is not ideal. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Of course I also have Product table with brand_id and subsubcategory_id